# Best way to search a plain text string in an HTML string in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

This is the html string :

```
 string htmlString = "<body lang=\"EN-US\" link=\"blue\" vlink=\"#954F72\"><div class=\"WordSection1\"><p class=\"MsoNormal\">Hi, </p><p class=\"MsoNormal\"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><p class=\"MsoNormal\"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><p class=\"MsoNormal\">My name is Gaurav Illness.</p><p class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"color:purple !important\">Today <b>MY&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; relation</b>ship breakdown <span style=\"color:red\">happened?<o:p></o:p></span> </span></p><p class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"color:red\"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><p class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"color:red\">I am Gr</span><span style=\"font-size:15.0pt;color:red;background:yellow;mso-highlight:yellow\">iESh and I</span><span style=\"font-size:15.0pt;color:red\"><o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"font-size:15.0pt;color:#B4C7E7;mso-style-textfill-fill-color:#B4C7E7;mso-style-textfill-fill-alpha:100.0%\">Am drugger.<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=\"MsoNormal\"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><p class=\"MsoNormal\" style=\"line-height:16.5pt\"><span style=\"font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:#1F497D\">Thanks<span style=\"text-transform:uppercase\">,<o:p></o:p>"
```

I am Extracting Plain text from this using this function :

```
     private static string extractTextFromHtml(string htmlString)
    {
        // Remove new lines since they are not visible in HTML
        html = html.Replace("\n", " ");

        // Remove tab spaces
        html = html.Replace("\t", " ");

        // Remove multiple white spaces from HTML
        html = Regex.Replace(html, "\\s+", " ");

        // Remove HEAD tag
        html = Regex.Replace(html, "<head.*?</head>", ""
                            , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);

        // Remove any JavaScript
        html = Regex.Replace(html, "<script.*?</script>", ""
          , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);

        // Replace special characters like &, <, >, " etc.
        StringBuilder sbHTML = new StringBuilder(html);
        // Note: There are many more special characters, these are just
        // most common. You can add new characters in this arrays if needed
        string[] OldWords = {"&nbsp;", "&amp;", "&quot;", "&lt;", "&gt;", "&reg;", "&copy;", "&bull;", "&trade;"};
        string[] NewWords = { " ", "&", "\"", "<", ">", "Â®", "Â©", "â€¢", "â„¢" };
        for (int i = 0; i < OldWords.Length; i++)
        {
            sbHTML.Replace(OldWords[i], NewWords[i]);
        }

        // Check if there are line breaks (<br>) or paragraph (<p>)
        sbHTML.Replace("<br>", "\n<br>");
        sbHTML.Replace("<br ", "\n<br ");
        sbHTML.Replace("<p ", "\n<p ");

        // Finally, remove all HTML tags and return plain text
        return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(
          sbHTML.ToString(), "<[^>]*>", "");
    }
```

This function returns :

"Hi,

My name is Gaurav Illness.
Today MY     relationship breakdown happened?

I am GriESh and I
Am drugger.

Thanks,"

Now I send this Text to an API that detects weather there is an emotion or not in these sentences. The API gives a response of all the sentences which are emotional. For example, API says "Today MY     relationship breakdown happened?" is emotional. Now I want to mark this sentence as purple color in the html for which I have to add a span around the sentence. To do this I have to find the start and end index of this sentence in the html code.

How can I find the start and end index of this sentence in the html code?

I have a code which gives me the indexes but I think it is not the best way to do. Can anyone suggest a better way?
This is my code example :

```
     public static void findTextInHtml(string htmlCode)
    {
        string textToBeFind = "I am GriESh and IAm drugger.";
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int startIndex = 0;
        int endIndex = 0;
        bool isHtml = false;
        bool isbeingMatched = false;
        while (i < htmlCode.Length)
        {
            if (htmlCode[i] == '<')
            {
                isHtml = true;
                i++;
                continue;
            }
            if (htmlCode[i] == '>')
            {
                isHtml = false;
                i++;
                continue;
            }
            if (isHtml)
            {
                i++;
                continue;
            }
            if (textToBeFind[j] == htmlCode[i])
            {
                if (!isbeingMatched)
                {
                    startIndex = i;
                }
                isbeingMatched = true;
                j++;
                if (j == textToBeFind.Length)
                {
                    endIndex = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                isbeingMatched = false;
                j = 0;
            }
            i++;
        }
        AddStartSpan(startIndex, htmlCode);
        AddEndSpan(endIndex, htmlCode);
    }
```

Comment: Please post any attempts you've made so far.

Comment: Use a HTML parsing library like AngleSharp (newer) or HtmlAgilityPack (older) and use `document.body.innerText` or `document.body.textContent`.

Comment: It's impossible to get a meaningful "start index" because HTML is a structured document, but you're searching for plain-text that can span and straddle elements. For example, should the "start index" include the first character of any surrounding elements' opening tags, for example? If not, then which elements' tags are meaningful for your search results?

Comment: I believe the best way is to use Regex.

Comment: @AndréSanson - Why do you believe that regex is the best way to accomplish this? It's not hard to find horror stories about how incredibly difficult it is to parse html with regex.

Comment: There are quite a few posts on SO that suggest that is definitely not the best way @AndréSanson

Comment: The question itself is not bad (in my personal opinion), although not well formulated I have seen worse questions with worse wording that have not closed.

Comment: @DourHighArch sorry my friend, this is the first time I'm asking a qiestion and this question is really difficult for me to explain without a whitboard and a marker.

Comment: Knowing of even worse questions is not an excuse for posting a bad question. If your question is too complex to explain then you need to [simplify your problem](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/) and solve that first to make progress.

Comment: @DourHighArch I have updated the question and tried to simplify as much as I can. Thanks

Comment: @BrootsWaymb I have updated the question, can you please have a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the nuget package `HtmlAgilityPack`
Then its easy to parse like this:

```
string htmlString = "<p class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"color:red\"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><p class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"color:red\">I am Gr</span><span style=\"font-size:15.0pt;color:red;background:yellow;mso-highlight:yellow\">iESh and I</span><span style=\"font-size:15.0pt;color:red\"><o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"font-size:15.0pt;color:#B4C7E7;mso-style-textfill-fill-color:#B4C7E7;mso-style-textfill-fill-alpha:100.0%\">Am drugger.<o:p></o:p></span></p>";
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(htmlString);

var inner = doc.DocumentNode.InnerText.TrimStartString("&nbsp;");
// inner = I am GriESh and IAm drugger.
```

To remove the `nbsp;` at the start of the InnerText

```
public static string TrimStartString(this string input, string prefixToRemove,
    StringComparison comparisonType = StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
{
    if (input != null && prefixToRemove != null
      && input.StartsWith(prefixToRemove, comparisonType))
    {
        return input.Substring(prefixToRemove.Length);
    }
    else return input;
}
```

Comment: Only problem with this solution is I am not able to get new lines.